# If $H \lhd G$, is there a homomorphism $φ$ from $G$ such that $H = \text{Ker}(φ)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the text usually read something like "if $N$ is a kernel of some homomorphism...", I wonder if there's a proof that given a normal subgroup, then there must be a homomorphism that has that normal subgroup as its kernel.

Comment: Just to add to Tsemo Aristide's good answer: this is the content of the [First Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first isomorphism theorem says that if $h:X\to Y$ is a homomorphism,  then $h(X)\cong X/\operatorname {ker}h$.

Now just apply this to the canonical submersion $s:G\to G/N$, given by $s(g)=gN$.

Answer (score 4):

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the kernel of the quotient map $p:G\rightarrow G/N$ is $N$.

Comment: Yes, but is there a proof that there is always such a map?

Comment: The quotient map is the map which assigns to $x$, the subset of elements $xH=Hx$ (since $H$ is normal) you can show that it is a morphism of groups.

Answer (score 1):

Normal subgroups are for quotient groups. If a subgroup is not normal, you cant make G/N like a group.
You can look at "canonical homomorphism" that you say is this.